# Is it good idea to remove SecurityBundle from Symfony2 based app?

Tags: security, symfony

I am developing app which consume some webservice and display data in human readable way. 
Access control is not required - everyone is welcome to consume the content. Is it good idea to removing Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle() from bundle list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't use any of SecurityBundle's functionality it's save to remove it.

This can gain a bit of performance.

Remember to remove it from your composer.json aswell in this case.